# How to Archive old data by partitioning

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing sliding window partitioning to archive old data but i was able to archive only the first date data when i am trying to archive the second day data it is throwing the following error.

> Msg 4905, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 ALTER TABLE SWITCH statement
>   failed. The target table 'bank.dbo.tblFactsStaging' must be empty.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQQ7j.png)

The query i have used to move partitioning to archive table is

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblFacts
SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO dbo.tblFactsStaging
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to switch data into an already partitioned table, you need to specify a target partition. Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblFacts SWITCH PARTITION 1 TO dbo.tblFactsStaging partition 5;
```

The above assumed that the source and destination match in a lot of ways (file group, indexing, etc). When I've done this sort of thing in the past though, I've switched the data out into a non-partitioned table, made sure the indexing was right fit the eventual destination, that it was on the right file group, etc. Then I would switch that into the archive. I find doing it this way is a lot more flexible in that your live data and archive don't need to have the same indexing or data location.

Check [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library) for more information.

Edit: Here's a simple example of switching a partition between tables. Note that both tables use the same partition scheme (and, by extension, partition function) which makes things simple insofar as the source and target partition should always be the same and you only have to do any maintenance on the partition function (i.e. splitting and merging ranges) once. Also, be careful that any partition function maintenance is done well outside of the period actually being affected to minimize data movement. In my example, I'd want to archive the 2015-01-01 partition long after any data was being added to it and would want to create the 2016-01-01 partition well in advance of any data being added to it.

```
use tempdb;
create partition function [PF_PartitionTest] (date) 
as range right 
for values (
    '2015-01-01', 
    '2015-02-01',
    '2015-03-01',
    '2015-04-01',
    '2015-05-01',
    '2015-06-01',
    '2015-07-01',
    '2015-08-01',
    '2015-09-01',
    '2015-10-01',
    '2015-11-01',
    '2015-12-01'
);

create partition scheme [PS_PartitionTest]
as partition [PF_PartitionTest]
all to ([primary]);

create table dbo.PartitionTest (
    [ID] int identity not null,
    [PeriodDate] date not null,
    constraint [PK_PartitionTest] primary key clustered ([ID], [PeriodDate]),
    [Fluff] varchar(500) null
) on [PS_PartitionTest] ([PeriodDate]);

insert into dbo.PartitionTest ([PeriodDate])
select dateadd(day, Number, '2014-12-31') 
from dbadmin.dbo.Numbers
where Number <= 365;

select *, $Partition.[PF_PartitionTest]([PeriodDate])
from dbo.PartitionTest;

create table dbo.PartitionTest_Archive (
    [ID] int identity not null,
    [PeriodDate] date not null,
    constraint [PK_PartitionTest_Archive] primary key clustered ([ID], [PeriodDate]),
    [Fluff] varchar(500) null
) on [PS_PartitionTest] ([PeriodDate]);

ALTER TABLE dbo.PartitionTest 
SWITCH PARTITION 2 
TO dbo.PartitionTest_Archive partition 2;

alter partition function [PF_PartitionTest]()
merge range ('2015-01-01');

alter partition function [PF_PartitionTest]()
split range ('2016-01-01');


select min([PeriodDate]), max([PeriodDate])
from dbo.PartitionTest;

select min([PeriodDate]), max([PeriodDate])
from dbo.PartitionTest_Archive;
```

Comment: Hi @Ben Thul,
The destination table was non partitioned table(normal table).

Comment: That may be you desired end state, but that's not how you'd do it mechanically. You'd need to create an empty partition in your archive table, switch the data into it, and then merge the two positions into one to do what your looking to do.